# WiX: Update version number displayed in Add/Remove Programs

Tags: wix, wix3.5, wyupdate

I use [WyUpdate](http://wyday.com/wyupdate/) to automatically deliver program updates so my customers are always running the latest version. However one problem with this approach is that the MSI installer (created with WiX 3.5) is not invoked during updates and thus the version numbers in **Add/Remove Programs** are not incremented.

My question is if there is some safe way to programmatically bump the displayed version ?(WyUpdate has the ability to execute custom code and change registry values during updates).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change the "DisplayVersion" value to the latest version.

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\YourAppName
```

Also, to save time, in [wyBuild](http://wyday.com/wybuild/) you can [use the %version% variable](http://wyday.com/wybuild/help/registry.php) and every new version you create will use correct version (instead of having to type it each time you release a new version).

Regarding what Yan said...

> BUT I don't think it is a good idea. Modifying the registry keys you don't owe, and injecting your own logic into the Windows Installer might lead to unexpected consequences. I would personally never do this. Sooner or later, it will shoot...

This is plain wrong. Editing a registry value isn't changing the installer logic. It isn't dangerous at all. The end-user can still repair the original installation (reverting the registry and all the files back to the original version) and they can run the uninstaller and it will remove the registry and files (despite them being changed).

If don't want the "msi repair" to revert to the original installation (rather than to the updated version of your app) then you'll want to deliver an *.msp or *.msi to your users and [execute it as part of your update](http://wyday.com/wybuild/help/executing-files.php).

Short answer: **editing registry is neither evil nor unsafe, as long as you understand what's what.**

Comment: Updating resources (files, registry keys, etc.) installed by the Windows Installer without updating the MSI that installed the resources is generally a really bad idea. If the MSI is repaired then changes made outside the installer may be lost, which is rarely what is intended when updating.

Yan's comments are probably more often correct than not. If you know exactly what you are doing and you are okay with the side-effects that will be introduced then you can go poking around.

However, the blanket statement that directly editing installed registry is safe is definitely *false*.

Comment: "...which is rarely what is intended when updating" -- That's true. I've clarified my response.

Comment: repairs causing the app to be reverted back to the original installed version is not a problem in my case as it will then just get re-updated later. Still I am intrigued by the ability to execute MSI's during updates and will try that and then report my findings.

Answer (score 4):

Technically, you can find a key in the system registry where the version is read from (typically, under SOFTWARE/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Uninstall) and force your update software to modify this value each time with the correct version.

BUT I don't think it is a good idea. Modifying the registry keys you don't owe, and injecting your own logic into the Windows Installer might lead to unexpected consequences. I would personally never do this. Sooner or later, it will shoot...

BTW, if you don't rely on Windows Installer with updates, why it is that important to update the version in ARP? Have a well-known place in your application where users can look for the current version, for instance.

Comment: I see your point and I would also like to avoid hacking WiX/MSI (I asked the question to figure out if there was some supported way of doing it). As for why I need the version updated in the add/remove programs its because my program is a service and this would properly be the easiest for our support crew to get version info from a customer.

Comment: Ah, service, I see... Well, hope someone here has better and safer ideas for you :)